# csc2.exe exited with code 1

Tags: c#, roslyn, visual-studio-2015

I'm playing with VS2015 and C# 6.0 compiler. Everything it great, but I suddenly started getting strange compilation error on one of my projects:

> "csc2.exe" exited with code 1.

I would love to provide as much data as needed, but I guess I don't have much:

- I have several project in the solution. All projects (excluding the project where I have unit tests) still compile without any problems.
- Quick googling did not help.
- I've looked into output, there isn't much: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(383,9): error MSB6006: "csc2.exe" exited with code 1.`
- VS restart as well as reboot didn't helped.
- Rollback of latest changes (but I can't give you 100% that I rolled back all of them) didn't help.

I'm stuck! I would appreciate any advice.

**UPDATE**

As @rene suggested I run `MSBuild.exe` with `/v:diag`. In the produced output I could finally find the root of the problem: I mistyped enum member name. I usually expect to see such errors in the error list, but they are not there until I open the file (where the error is taking the place). As soon as the file is opened in the VS, I can perfectly fine see all errors in the error list. 
Hope that this will be fixed by the next CTP.

Comment: Can you enable diagnostic logging for build?  (run msbuild with /v:diag)

Comment: Thanx for the solution. I run into the same problem

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was remote debugging my project dll through another visual studio. When I try to delete obj folder it failed to delete .pdb file. That triggered me that I have a visual studio left running. Closed it, retry build, boom, it worked fine. Just in case, check obj folder for any pdb file locks. That could also be a reason.